# Can you sell an item that already has a patent but your product differs in the ability to be customized?

Tags: patentability

I'm interested in selling a product for which there is currently a patent granted for the recipe on. I'd like to be able to offer customized features of this product - such as natural color dyes and scent upon ordering, thus making it a custom order which isn't currently offered anywhere. Is that legal to do?

Answer (score 2):

After customizing the color and the scent, does the end product possess all the features claimed in the patent? If yes, then it is still an infringement and I presume this is illegal in every country the patent exists.

For example, if the patent claims aromatic candles, which are made of features A, B and C and you provide aromatic candles with features A, B and C, plus color and scent customizing, then your product still falls into the scope of the claim. This is pretty much the definition of infringement.